# How to show to the user that a file is attached to an element

Tags: enterprise-architect

We are currently using a stereotype with an attached shape script to show that files are linked to an element

[image: here's an example]

However, going this route means that our users cannot use another stereotype, or it will overwrite (Even if multiple stereotypes can be applied, only one will be shown and only one shape script will be applied)

I tried using the "A" icon for when a linked document has been created for an element by modifying the style property of the element, but setting MDoc=1 without a linked document will not show the icon.

What would be an effective way of showing there are files linked to a document without using stereotypes(if any)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "files linked"? Embedded docs produce the `A` icon. Do you mean the `Related/Files` in the properties?

Comment: yes related files, not linked documents

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck here. The `Link to Element Feature` on Notes works for many things, but not for the related files.

In case you could link `<<files>>` stereotyped Notes to the elements and run a batch script that looks into the `Related/Files` and fills them in the Notes. Basically that would be something like:

```
for dia in all diagrams:
  for diaobj in dia.diagramobjects:
    obj = rep.GetElementByID(diaObj.ElementID)
    if obj.Type == "Note" and obj.Stereotype == "files":
      con = obj.connectors.getAt(0) # assume there's only one connected
      ident = con.clientId
      if ident == obj.ElementId: ident = obj.sourceId
      fObj = rep.GetElementByID(ident) # element connected to the note
      # parse fObj's files and write them as string to obj's Note attribute
```